# C++ test CIN on one line

Tags: c++, input

I've recently started teaching myself C++, and after having written a lot of user input code, it's made me wonder if there's a simpler way of handling it.

For example, the normal way of doing it would be like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int inp;
int guess = 13;

void main(){
    cout << "Guess a number: ";
    cin >> inp;
    if (inp == guess)
        cout << endl << "Nice.";
}
```

But what I want to do is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int guess = 13;

void main(){
    cout << "Guess a number: ";
    if (cin == guess)
        cout << endl << "Even nicer.";
}
```

Is there a way to do this? Or this that just improper C++ standard?

Comment: No you can't do so. The `operator>>()` is a function call actually.

Comment: You could do `if (cin >> inp && inp == guess) ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: No, it's not possible to do as you want it.

You need to understand, that `>>` is actually a function call of

```
template<typename T>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, T& result);
```

and `==` is a function call to

```
template<typename T>
bool operator==(const std::istream&,const T& x);
```

Where the latter is used to check the stream state, and doesn't extract any user input.

To compare the input the result needs to be extracted from the `std::istream` in 1st place.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do it in one line but you don't really need to. But here are some examples anyway

```
//This will work for a char
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char test = 'a';
    if (getch()== test)
        cout<<"\n Works";
    return 0;
}
```

And if you really want

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x =1;
    int y;
    for( cin >> y ; x == y ; )
    {
        cout<<"\n Works";
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Or as NathanOliver said you could simply do this

```
if( cin >> inp && inp == guess )
```

But really you want to keep it simple as this will confuse others as well as yourself after some time. You want to leave your code as easy as possible

Comment: Kind of an off topic question, but - Is it better to use int as the return type of main rather than void? I've always used void because I don't see the point of just returning 0. But in most of the code I've seen from other people, they use an integer return type for main.

Comment: @NeonWizard `void` isn't a well defined return type for `main()`, it's just visual studio accepting it.

Comment: Also some compilers wont accept `main()` without a return type, so its good practice to use `int main()` instead of `void main()`

Comment: I did some research and found out that the returned integer from main is basically the error code. 0 means everything went fine and dandy.